# Imbed Sobolev spaces of fractional order into Holder spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, besov-spaces

This result exist (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Imbedding_theorems ) for regular (i.e. not fractional) Sobolev spaces; looks like it's provable for fractional spaces through results for Besov space. Is it possible to derive a result like that without resorting to Besov spaces?

Comment: So something like section 8 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345)?

Comment: yes, that's *exactly* it! I searched through that paper, but evidently very poorly. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, is there a similar result for $s > 1$, for $s$ as in $W^{s, p}$?

Comment: I suppose then, the question to ask is what is the definition of $W^{s,p}$? If it is that $f\in L^p$ and $\nabla f\in W^{s-1,p}$ (like eqn (2.10) in the above link) then it should be easy to adapt

Comment: yeah, the only bit I'm tripping up on is proving that f is continuously differentiable. That holds for s = 2, and feels like it should hold for $s \in (1, 2)$ as well.

Comment: what's the difficulty, at least under the assumption $(s-1)p>n$?